# VBA Macro not working due to Subscript out of range exception

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

To create a VBA macro for appending data from 'Lot' excel to a 'Master' excel file sheetwise.
Expected results -
data in worksheet Sheet1  of 'Lot' excel file should be appended to worksheet Sheet1 of 'Master' excel file
data in worksheet XYZ of 'Lot' excel file should be appended to worksheet XYZ of 'Master' excel file. If a worksheet named XYZ does not exist in 'Master' excel file, then creates one.

I tried following code:

`Sub AppendDataFromLotToMaster()

```
' Define the file paths for the lot and master workbooks
Dim lotPath As String
Dim masterPath As String
lotPath = "somepath\Merge\lot1.xlsx"
masterPath = "somepath\Tf Master.xlsx"

' Open the lot workbook
Dim lotWb As Workbook
Set lotWb = Workbooks.Open(lotPath)

' Loop through each sheet in the lot workbook
Dim lotWs As Worksheet
For Each lotWs In lotWb.Worksheets
    
    ' Check if the sheet exists in the master workbook
    Dim masterWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set masterWs = Workbooks(masterPath).Worksheets(lotWs.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If the sheet doesn't exist, create it
    If masterWs Is Nothing Then
        (----ERROR ON THIS LINE----)Set masterWs = Workbooks(masterPath).Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) 
        masterWs.Name = lotWs.Name
    End If
    
    ' Find the last row in the master sheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = masterWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Copy the data from the lot sheet to the master sheet
    lotWs.Range("A1", lotWs.Cells(lotWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count, lotWs.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Copy
    masterWs.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
Next lotWs

' Close the lot workbook
lotWb.Close SaveChanges:=False End Sub`
```

Following code generates error 'Subscript out of range' at code marked in bold.
Files I am testing -
lot1.xlsx with Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 with 3 sample rows each.
TF Master.xlsx is empty

Comment: Problem is with `Workbooks(masterPath)`. masterPath should be the filename without the path `masterPath = "Tf Master.xlsx"`

Comment: `Workbooks(index)` must be used for referencing an **opened** workbook and yours is not opened. If `masterPath` references an existing workbook, you must firs open it like you did with `Set lotWb = Workbooks.Open(lotPath)`. If it's a new workbook. first you must do something like `Set masterWB = Workbooks.Add` and then later on you could save it in the path you got stored in `masterPath`

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheets to Another Workbook

```vb
Sub AppendDataFromLotToMaster()

    ' Define the file paths for the lot and master workbooks
    Dim lotPath As String
    Dim masterPath As String
    lotPath = "somepath\Merge\lot1.xlsx"
    masterPath = "somepath\Tf Master.xlsx"
    
    ' Open the lot workbook
    Dim lotWb As Workbook: Set lotWb = Workbooks.Open(lotPath)
    
    ' Reference the master workbook
    Dim masterWb As Workbook
    ' If it is open:
    Set masterWb = Workbooks("Tf Master.xlsx")
    ' If it is closed, open it:
    'Set masterWb = Workbooks.Open(masterPath)
    
    ' Declare new For Each...Next loop variables.
    Dim lotWs As Worksheet, masterWs As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    
    ' Loop through each sheet in the lot workbook
    For Each lotWs In lotWb.Worksheets
        
        ' Check if the sheet exists in the master workbook
        On Error Resume Next
            Set masterWs = masterWb.Worksheets(lotWs.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If the sheet doesn't exist, create it
        If masterWs Is Nothing Then
            With masterWb
                Set masterWs = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            End With
            masterWs.Name = lotWs.Name
        End If
        
        ' Find the last row in the master sheet
        lastRow = masterWs.Cells(masterWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Copy the data from the lot sheet to the master sheet
        With lotWs
            .Range("A1", .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Cells.CountLarge)).Copy
        End With
        masterWs.Cells(lastRow + 1, "A") _
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        
        Set masterWs = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration!!!
        
    Next lotWs
    
    ' Close the lot workbook
    lotWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    MsgBox "Lot data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```